firestore how to get list of orphaned documents
I am developing a firestore CLI tool called firebatch
I read that to properly delete a collection and to avoid orphaned documents, you have to traverse all subcollections and delete them first.
I have a basic implementation of the delete command but I would like to test if it properly works.
For that I need to check if the deletion of a collection left any orphaned collections or documents behind. How do I do that(preferably in python)?

Firestore doesn't have any definition of an orphaned document, but I think you mean a document in a subcollection for which the parent document does not exist.
If that is indeed what you want to find, you can use a collection group query to find all documents in a collection with a given name, and then for each of them check if its parent document exists (via the path of the DocumentSnapshot.reference. For more on this, see: How to get Document Name from DocumentReference in Firestore Python and Is there a way in firestore to get full document path for documents retrieved using collection_group query in python?
There is no specific operation to find these types of documents (as there's no index for this condition), so you'll end up also reading the documents for which a parent document does exist.
